# Server Date resolving issue

Tags: php, date, time

```
$eve['start']['dateTime'] = 2013-05-02T14:00:00+05:30;

$current_date = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($eve['start']['dateTime'])); 

$start_time = date("H:i A",strtotime($eve['start']['dateTime']));
```

when i use the above code am getting it as `05-02-2013 08:30 AM`

But i should get `05-02-2013 2:00 PM`

why this time difference and shows wrong any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The *time difference* is not wrong.  You are getting the correct date and time for a timezone at +0:00.  To fix this, [set your timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

your formatters seems to be incorrect, to get the desired output use the code below. `H` is used for 24 hour format with leading zero. `h` is used for 12 hour format.

```
date("h:i A");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$eve['start']['dateTime'] = "2013-05-02T14:00:00+05:30"; // Missing quotes in your code?
$current_date = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($eve['start']['dateTime']));
```

Should return `05-02-2013 08:30 AM` because your server has timezone sat to GMT+0. If you take `14:00` and subtracts with 5 and a half hour (from +0530 to +0000), it should be `08:30`.

To avoid this, you have to [set default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) on your server or in your script.